# Restore saved worlds from PS4 Minecraft to new copy of the game

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4, ps5

Our old Minecraft disk is scratched and hardly readable (needs toothpaste treatment on every insert) so we bought a new disk, thinking we could switch to that without problem. But the console (PS5, but the games are PS4 version) treats them as two separate applications.

The problem is that the old worlds are only visible when playing from the old disk, and it treats the new disk as a completely different save folder - nothing visible there.

How can I move the old worlds to the new copy of the game?

I tried backing up to a USB from old and new, and I can see that the saved worlds from each version are in two separate folders, `CUSA00744` and `CUSA00265`. I tried to move the old worlds to the new folder, but if I do that it complains that the save data is corrupt.

Just to be clear: both the old worlds and the new worlds are in Bedrock format, so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CUSA00744](https://serialstation.com/titles/CUSA/00744) is a US copy, while [CUSA00265](https://serialstation.com/titles/CUSA/00265) is an European copy. It appears that you can't transfer saved data between different regions of Minecraft BE in PS4.

Your only options in this case are the transfer of saved data between copies via Realms or sell/trade the disc for one with the same product code.

Transferring the worlds via realms is very simple. You would upload the world with the old copy and then download the world with the new copy. Repeat this for every world that you have. There is a free month of Realms that you can use so this should not be a problem if is your first time using Realms.

You can also sell the new disc and buy one that has the exact same product code as the old disc. If you are unable to find one with the same product code, one with in the same region will probably also work but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I'll try the Realms approach (I do think I should be able to use the trial edition for this).